# Remove empty space of ImageView xml

Tags: android, material-design

I need to remove empty space from the start and the end of ImageView, like on the picture.

[image]

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/z"
               android:id="@+id/imageView" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:lines="2"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="New Text"
              android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Need like this:**

[image]

Comment: can you post your image?

Answer (score 0):

I think your image height should be wrap_content or you can use fixed height & width.

```
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/z"
                   android:id="@+id/imageView"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: It is necessary not to use fixed size

Comment: why do you use  android:layout_weight="1" in text view.. And can you please tell your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think your image height is much greater than match_parent its attr.
And again imageview's scale type

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

forces image to resize width in accordance to its height, and hence the blank space.

Comment: The image size should be changed depending on the size of the text

Comment: Mate, you need to resize down that image considering most probable height to texview. Thereafter if textview font size increases beyond a limit, image would strech. OR try resizing imageview programmatically in accordance with textview/layout height. 
I don't think there is a way of acheiving your exact requirement using xml only

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="New Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This changes the image size, but not the internal layout

Comment: What do you actually want to do ? @IQ.feature

Comment: Change the size of the image depending on the size of the text

Answer (score 0):

Resize your image as per @G.Dator said. But if you don't want to resize an image.Try to give a size of layout_width from values in **dp** according to screen size like values, value-large, values-xlarge.

> android:layout_width="@dimen/xyz"